# Help proof regarding sequence in subset of Hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

I'm to prove the following:

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and let $M$ be a non-empty convex subset of $H$.

Suppose that $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $M$ such that $ ||x_n|| \to d$, where $d= \inf \{||x||:x \in M \}$. Show that $(x_n)$ converges in $H$.

Is it enough to claim the following:

Let $d=||x||$. It follows from the continuity of $|| \cdot||$ that 
$$||x_n|| \to d \; \text{as} \; x_n \to x$$

Hence $(x_n)$ converges to some $x$ in $H$.

Comment: You cannot assume that there is a specific $x \in H$ such that $\|x\|=d$. That is precisely what you are trying to prove. In any case, even if there is some $x \in H$ with $\|x\|=d$, there is no reason that this $x$ should be unique. You therefore cannot conclude that $x_n \to x$ given only $\|x_n\| \to d$

Comment: Note also that your argument didn't refer to $M$, but the statement to be proved depends crucially on the relationship between $d$ and $M$.  (Without that condition, there are simple counterexamples, e.g., take $x_n$ to be the standard basis vectors, $d=1$, and $M$ to be the closed unit ball.)

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Use the equality:

$$||\frac{x_n - x_m}{2}||^2 + ||\frac{x_n + x_m}{2}||^2= 1/2\,(\,||x_n||^2 + ||x_m||^2)$$

$M$ is convex so $\frac{x_n + x_m}{2}$ also have norm approaching $d$.